# In Django Admin searching by a Relational Key(1to1)

Tags: django, django-admin

I have two models Owner and Entity with OneToOne Relationship.

```
class Owner(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    .....
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Entity(models.Model):
    owner = models.OneToOneField(Owner, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
    ......
```

For Django Admin, search fields I have:

```
class EntityAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    .....
    search_fields = ('email', 'name', 'owner')
```

If I try to search I get the following error:

```
 Related Field got invalid lookup: icontains
```

If I remove `owner`, but I still want to search by `owner`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.search_fields) show, you need to follow the relationship to an actual text field. So:

```
search_fields = ('email', 'name', 'owner__name')
```